# Javascript HTML DOM is not working in Browser but html, css and js files work

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsdom

I am learning JS from one YT tutorial - I followed the exact same code, taught in the tutorial, but I didn't get proper output.

**Output showed in Tutorial after entering the Input in prompt:**
[image]

**Output I got after entering the input in prompt(Entering year of birth):**
[image]

**Code:**

**index.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <title>Javascript on Steroids</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container-1">
        <h2>Challenge 1: Your Age in Days</h2>
        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary" onclick="ageInDays()">Click me</button>
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-danger" onclick="reset()">Reset</button>
        </div>
        </div>

        <div class="flex-box-container-1">
            <div id="flex-box-result">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src = "js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**script.js**

```
//challenge 1: your age in days
function ageInDays() {
    var birthyear = prompt("What year where you born ");
    var age =  (2021 - birthyear) * 360;
    let h1 = document.createElement('h1');
    let textAnswer = document.createTextNode("You are "+ age + " days old");
    h1.setAttribute('id', 'ageInDays');
    h1.appendChild(textAnswer);
    document.getElementsById("flex-box-result").appendChild(h1);
}

function reset() {
    document.getElementById("ageInDays").remove();
```

**style.css**

```
.container-1 {
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.flex-box-container-1{
    display: flex;
    border : 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    flex-wrap: wrap; 
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-box-container-1 div{
    display: flex;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: last line of the function `ageInDays()`: you should have `getElementById()` ("Element" without "s")

Comment: ... and, by the way, one year is 365 days, not 360 (and you are not taking into consideration leap years) ;)

Comment: I suggest closing the question, as the issue is cause by a simple typo

Comment: Two typos 1. ageInDay and 2.getElementById also close your reset function there is a missing }

Answer (score 1):

use

```
document.getElementById("flex-box-result").appendChild(h1);
```

istead of

```
 document.getElementsById("flex-box-result").appendChild(h1);
```